# Get IP Address of Main Interface in Ubuntu and Mac

Tags: bash, scripting, ip

I need to write a script that gets the IP address of the interface that is used for unknown routes (e.g. where 0.0.0.0/0 is routed through)

That script should work on Ubuntu, Debian, Arch and Mac OS Systems without the need of installing extra packages.

On Ubuntu, I use `hostname -I`, that gives the primary IP address. But in older versions of ubuntu, debian and arch and in Mac OS the `-I`-Flag is not available.

Second Idea was to parse the `ifconfig`-output, but as the naming is very different on each system and in german systems for example there is no `addr:` but something different, this also won't work.

I need this to write a little script to start up a web-application and a little Python-Webserver to server the static content. The script is then used by our designers that barely can code some html and css but don't know anything about bash.

Comment: By the way - none of this works in my default ubuntu 15.04 config: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13322485/how-to-i-get-the-primary-ip-address-of-the-local-machine-on-linux-and-os-x

Comment: You need to check the default route; in linux e.g. `ip ro get 192.0.0.0` and check what IP address is shown after `src`. I'm sure MacOS has something similar but I think it's wrong to expect one command to work across operating systems. Wrap your check with an OS check. EDIT: this whould work just fine on ubuntu 15.04, you may have to add /sbin and /usr/sbin to your PATH first. Otherwise add to the question why it doesn't work (i.e. edit it, don't add comments for such additional info)

Answer (score 0):

The command `route` gives you information about the routes used to access different ip address and also de device name.

```
$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
10.0.0.0        *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 eth0
default         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

I think the command is available in all systems you mention.